# how to get the value of the button and display it on edittext?

Tags: java, android, performance

my application generate random numbers in the buttons. and if you click a button i want to display the value of the button in the edittext but i dont have idea how to do it?:( can someone help me with this? ps: the numbers in the buttons are random so everytime the app is run, the number in the buttons change. i have tried this but nothing happens...

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
hold=b1.getText().toString();
    et1.setText(hold);
        }
    });
```

hold is a empty String.
b1 is the button.
et1 is the edittext.

Comment: if the button has number displayed then try use `v.getText()` instead of `b1.getText()` in onClick() method

Comment: @djhs16 the method getText() is undefined for the type View

Comment: Apology @dreamer1989, I slipped. It can be cast to `Button` like `((Button)v).getText()`.

Comment: @djhs16,i have used the ((Button)v).getText(). it works. thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

To get the text of the button, you need to use the `getText()` method.
You can get more details here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 0):

To set random number on your button:-

```
int random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
b1.setText(""+random);
```

and then your button clicklistener is fine for getting text from button.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
hold=b1.getText().toString();
et1.setText(hold);
    }
});
```